# Resource temporarily unavailable in Docker container when connecting to grpc endpoint

Tags: c#, docker, docker-compose, grpc

I am trying to connect to my grpc service within a docker container however when my code runs to connect it gives out a Resource Temporarily Unavailable error.

Docker-compose for dev container.
I spin this up using: **docker-compose -f .devcontainer/docker-compose.yml up**

```
version: "3.8"
services:
    app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        # Update 'VARIANT' to pick a version of .NET: 3.1, 5.0, 6.0
        VARIANT: "6.0"
        # Optional version of Node.js
        NODE_VERSION: "lts/*"
    image: company/devcontainer:latest
    environment:
      - UNIT_TESTS=/workspace/test
      - ACCEPTANCE=/workspace/acceptance
      - DOCKER_HOSTNAME=host.docker.internal

    # Attaches Host Docker Daemon to devcontainer and directories
    volumes:
      - ..:/workspace:cached
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Docker-compose for grpc service

```
version: "3.8"
services:
    my-app:
        image: ${MY_APP_IMAGE_NAME:-company/my-app}
        restart: on-failure
        ports:
          - '3000:3000'
        extra_hosts:
          - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

C# Code to connect to my-app which is a grpc service

```
using var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(
                "http://my-app:3000",
                channelOptions: new GrpcChannelOptions() {
                    Credentials = Grpc.Core.ChannelCredentials.Insecure
                });
```

When I run the test locally with visual studio using localhost:3000 it works fine.
I spin up everything using the docker-compose up command. Once I try to use my grpc channel I get resource temporarily unavailable but I do see the service spin up within docker.

Comment: Shouldn't you connect to localhost:3000 also? Or wherever the docker host is running?

Comment: @Ralf When I try to use localhost inside the container it says: Cannot assign requested address

Comment: You first said client so i was expecting your call is from outside of docker into docker. So your grpc call is between docker images running on the same docker network? You just show one service from your docker-compose file but there are multiple?

Comment: Are they defined in the same `docker-compose.yaml` files? I.e. are they running on the same network?

Comment: @Artur Sorry Im having a hard time explaining this as its new to me, I have a container which I boot up. Inside that container I run some tests that include the C# code seen above. The grpc service I am trying to reach exists within a different docker-compose file which the code for that is above. So I guess the answer to your question is no they arent running on same network because they exist in two different docker-compose files?

Comment: Yeah, different docker-compose files start services in different networks, that's why you can't reach the other service using its name. You need to specify the network explicitly on both services and use the same network name. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#networks-top-level-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I noted in the comments, the problem is running services on different networks. **One possible** solution would be to create a network manually

```
docker network create my-network
```

Then set the default external network in both docker-compose files

```yaml
networks:
  default:
    external: true
    name: my-network
```

For more info: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#networks-top-level-element

Comment: Thank you! Do I also need the specify the network name under the service itself? Or since its the default the service should automatically use that?

Comment: No, as it was specified as `default`.